# Google Apps Script: Batch Create Calendar Events with Variable Inputs for CalendarID

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a task-scheduler that can read an a Google Sheet full of tasks (task name, start time, end time, person-assigned-to) and automatically create a calendar event on the specified person's calendar.

This tutorial:https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/g-suite-pro-tip-how-to-automatically-add-a-schedule-from-google-sheets-into-calendar

...has basically all I need, except that it only takes a single CalendarID, whereas I think I need the CalendarID to be part of the loop.

The CalendarID's in this case are all email addresses.

Here's what I tried:

```
function scheduleTasks() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("E9:H13").getValues();
for (x=0; x<signups.length;x++)
{
    var shift = signups[x];
    var calendarID = shift[3];
    var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
    var task= shift[0];
    var startTime = shift[1];
    var endTime = shift[2];
    eventCal.createEvent(volunteer, startTime, endTime);
}
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar')
  .addItem('Schedule tasks now', 'scheduleTasks')
  .addToUi();
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

> 8:38:40 AM    Error    TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of
> null scheduleTasks    @ Code.gs:12

Never used JS/Google Apps Script before now so any advice is appreciated,
Thanks

[my input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQTWZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- `calendarId` of `var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);` is not declared. From your script and your showing sample image, I thought that `calendarId` is `var calendarID = shift[3];`.
- `volunteer` is not declared. From your showing sample image, I thought that `var task = shift[0]` might be `volunteer`.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function scheduleTasks() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("E9:H13").getValues();
  for (x = 0; x < signups.length; x++) {
    var shift = signups[x];
    var calendarID = shift[3];
    var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);
    var task = shift[0];
    var startTime = shift[1];
    var endTime = shift[2];
    eventCal.createEvent(task, startTime, endTime);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, when the calendar ID is not existing and you have not the write permission to the calendar of the calendar ID and the values of `startTime, endTime` are not the date objects, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Ah, this seems to be working. Thank you!

The error for missing permissions isn'g a big problem, since I'll need to make sure I have all permissions I need before I can deploy this... But I will need to be able to skip over rows where "calendarID" is empty... Would it make sense to put an 'if' statement after 'calendarID' is declared so that it only attempts to make the calendar event if the value is true?

Comment: @dylan-bush Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, in that case, I think that how about putting `if (!eventCal) continue;` just after the line of `var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);`? By this, when `calendarID` is invalid, it is skipped. If this was not useful for your additional question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Just gave it a go and this seems to be working:

```
function scheduleTasks() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("E9:H13").getValues();
for (x=0; x<signups.length;x++)
{
    var shift = signups[x];
    var calendarID = shift[3];
    if(calendarID){
      var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);
      var task= shift[0];
      var startTime = shift[1];
      var endTime = shift[2];
      eventCal.createEvent(task, startTime, endTime);
    }

}
}
```